# What changes we need to make to a theme so it can be installed as a MU Theme?

Tags: customization, themes, multisite, options

I downloaded the free [Wootheme](http://www.woothemes.com/themes/) [Irrestible](http://www.woothemes.com/2009/02/irresistible/) and **if installed on a stand alone Wordpress**, works **very well**.

Now, if we **enable Multiple Sites** on 3.x and set this theme to be the theme of a new site it simply **does not work** out-of-the-box.

As WooThemes Support is only for paid customers, and being this a free theme, I can ask for support directly, so I'm kindly ask here for any help.

current site with IrrestibleTheme using WP 3.0.1 multi site enable is located at

> http://fortiusfitness.com/fblog

website settings:

[image]

As I don't know what might be wrong, here is all settings to this 2nd website:

- [settings](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-20_0020.png)
- [more settings](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-20_0020_001.png)
- [and more](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-20_0021.png)
- [and more](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-20_0022.png)
- [and more](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-20_0023.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to specify how it does not work. There are no multisite-specific theme tags. 99% of the themes out there for WordPress work in a network.

If you're getting errors, check your error logs.

If it's not grabbing image th8umbnails, that's a known issue - not with multisite or the timthumb script, but how the theme itself calls the images.

http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2009/10/timthumb-wordpress-mu/

Edit: actually, I have tested the Irresistible theme in mu. Worked for me. A quick checked reveals it's looking for images in a subfolder that is not there.

Comment: no errors, just what the page shows, looking at the code, CSS is not loading, but I have no idea what are the setup that I need to set. All values are the default values. If I use the same theme (exactly same files) in the first website, works like a charm.

Comment: regarding the images, it's looking at the right places and all images are there (or you couldn't see the myWrittings img) -> http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-26_1758.png

Comment: as a personal question, what trick do we need to do to use `domain.com/blog` as `blog` is a keyword and we can't use to specify a sub website?

Comment: I downloaded a fresh installation and uploaded again, started to work ok :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using WordPress 3.0+ then by default any new themes are not enabled for multisite.

1. You must log in as a Super Admin
2. click on the Themes option in the left.
3. Find your theme and click ON to enable this on other blogs in the network.

Go to WordPress Super Admin http://codex.wordpress.org/Super_Admin_Themes_SubPanel